# Google Cloud SQL Network throughput is full

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My applications is running in Google Cloud Platform and uses Cloud SQL.

In Cloud Console > SQL > Instance Details > Edit > "Configure machine type and storage" network throughput is 2000 of 2000 MB/s ([pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fBtMlgc499yIlrdoi-Qtwaaln1Dq3Hra)).

How can I further raise the throughput?

Comment: Are you asking because Cloud SQL is hitting the network throughput limit during it's usage or do you want to raise the limit proactively?

Answer (score 1):

The access to network for Cloud SQL is provided through VPC and is therefore [limited](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#egress_throughput_caps) by it to 2000MB/s(16Gbps):

> Each additional vCPU increases the network cap, up to a theoretical maximum of 16 Gbps for each virtual machine.

Which means this is a hard limit and will only raise when Google upgrades it's infrastructure.

If you want higher read throughput you can further expand it by adding some [read replicas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/).